# minimum of $\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-c^Tx$ subject to $Ax=b$

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-programming, operations-research

minimum of $\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-c^Tx$ subject to $Ax=b$

How do you prove that an objective function is convex if all of the eigenvalues of Q are positive? I have been researching but cannot figure out this problem.

Comment: If $Q$ is positive definite, then the function $x^TQx$ is strictly convex. A quick Google search returns https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function.

Comment: If it is symmetric then yes. The second derivative of the cost is ${ 1 \over 2} (Q+Q^T)$.

Comment: $Q$ can be assumed without loss of generality to be symmetric. Assume it is not, and let $\hat{Q}=\frac{1}{2}\left(Q + Q^T\right).$ Since $x^T \hat{Q} x = x^T Q x,$ you can replace $Q$ with $\hat{Q}$ in the objective without changing the function.